month and year wise label on X-axis in Vega Lite
I am trying to create over time series data data in vegalite that is similar to

how i show multiple label on x-axis by Jan wise separation by extending tickline
i want to show more extended tick line for every jan means year change and also want to show year along with month
refernce link "https://jsfiddle.net/gvku7otL/1/"

Documentation shows how to do this here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#example-conditional-axis-properties-and-multi-line-axis-label

